# Logging Java servlet actions

Tags: java, servlets, logging

I'm new to writing java servlets (came from PHP) so I am not familiar with the best way to do *logging* (crashes, as well as exceptions I want to throw such as too many login attempts).

There appears to be a `Logger` (`java.util.logger`), but I've also heard that there are better loggers for web apps.  Is there a gold standard logger for this kind of work?

Comment: Log4J is absolutely the "gold standard" for most J2EE stuff: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of logging frameworks in Java. [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/index.html) provides a simple facade for most of these so you can  easily exchange the concrete implementation you are using.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by paulsm4 Log4j is often considered the standard.
However if you don t have a specific need and since you state you are a beginner (but even if you were not)  I would stick with java.logging it will most likely handle all your needs without adding new dependencies. It can also be customized further down line.

Comment: I dunno...  java.logging is pretty limited.  I'd suggest using slf4j or log4j. Better, find out what the container is using (Tomcat uses log4j for example), and use that.

Comment: Tomcat is using java.util.Logging since at least v6.0

Comment: Ah yes - Tomcat uses Apache Commons Logging, and they do default their loggers to use JUL.  But it is easy to set up with log4j - here's the full documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html